# unable to reference object/instance variable in separate ruby file for automation test

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Ruby Newbie here!  I am re-writing automated unit tests.  The problem is that there are too many 'test users' that get changed and used by others.  So the goal is to make a list of test users for each repository, and have them referenced in a specific file rather than hard-coding the email/password logins.  I am unable to figure out how to have: 
1.  the .feature file with the test 
2.  the steps.rb with the steps for the test
3.  a final user.rb file that holds class/instance variables (I don't care which I use, it just has to be able to be referenced by all the tests I will be re-writing).

I've tried referencing the email/password details from the steps.rb file in these ways:
* Then('User enters \”([^\”]*)\”$”')
* Then('User enters ')
* Then('User enters '/valid_user_email>')

I've tried defining the email/password in user.rb in these ways:
* @valid_user_email = 'user@url.com'
* puts 'valid_user_email' = 'user@url.com'
*  = 'user@url.com'

Currently the login.feature file is:

```
Feature: Login and Logout of MySE

  Scenario: Login and Logout of MySE
    Given I enter the email address of an existing account
    Then User enters valid_user_email in the email field
```

The login_steps.rb file looks like:

```
Given('I enter the email address of an existing account') do
  visit "user/profiles"
  expect(page).to have_content('Welcome')
end

Then('User enters valid_user_email in the email field') do
  fill_in 'user_login', with: @valid_user_email
  click_on('Next')
end
```

And finally, the user.rb file looks like:

```
class Credentials
  def valid_user_email
    @valid_user_email = "user@url.com"
  end

  def valid_user_password
    puts "Testttttt01"
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception? If so what is the error message and stack trace?

Comment: What about saying `Credentials.new.valid_user_email` from your step definition file? I don't think `@valid_user_email` is available in the scope you're trying to access it from. You could also make it a class method so you don't have to pointlessly initialize Credentials

Comment: using 'Credentials.new.valid_user_email' worked!  Thanks, and in regards to Greg's question.  I was not getting any errors, but it wasn't inputting anything and I didn't have any conditions that were checking.  But I'm curious, how would I make it a class method (apologies if this is the wrong kind of question to ask)